# Restarting speakers without rebooting?

Tags: macbook-pro, speakers

My MacBook Pro internal speaker has crashed, as it does every few months. I'm sure a reboot will fix it, but wondering if there's any way I could restore the speaker without rebooting? (Setting things back up again is time-consuming.)

UPDATE: It didn't actually work after reboot. I noticed the headphone slot is red, [like in this picture](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?p=6618965#post6618965), so it seems it's trying to serve optical out, since MBP uses the same slot as explained in that thread.

UPDATE 2: Best solution I've seen is here. https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4220803?start=0&tstart=
Note that it's fiddly and you might need to reboot before re-trying the headphones.

Comment: What do you mean that your speaker has "crashed"? Does it simply not work? Have you visited an Apple Store or Apple reseller to see if they can fix it?

Comment: Have you tried anything like a [SMC reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3964) or [PRAM reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379)?

Comment: CajunLuke, it's not a hardware issue. It just does this sometimes. da4 no, just asking if there's a way to do it without reboot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sometimes changing the sound output from your system preferences > sound panel will reinitialize the connection to your hardware. If you only have one output device available, try installing [soundflower](http://cycling74.com/soundflower-landing-page/), just to have a second output in your list that you can cycle through.

[image: System Pref pane]

Also: setting things back up after a reboot is a snap with snow leopard. It can remember which apps you had open and reopen them for you.

Comment: WRT setting things back up - see my previous questions on here. Setting up a dev environment isn't easily automated.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. I switched to SoundFlower and also a USB headset (which works fine).

Comment: Time to hit the genius bar... sounds like a hardware problem.

Comment: This isn't a hardware problem I know of, just something that randomly happens once every few months when I pull the headphones out. (Which is why I'm back here.)

Comment: Time to hit the genius bar... sounds like a software problem.

Comment: Once again I've solved it by some combination of resetting the PRAM and putting headphones in and out of the socket.

Comment: Is it possible that the headphone port is dodgy, and isn't registering the fact that you've removed the headphones?

Comment: It's only happened a few times and always fixed itself after some reboots, updates, and messing around.

Comment: kill them all! it works!

Answer (score 50):

Try restarting the daemon process that processes audio by typing in Terminal:

```
sudo killall coreaudiod
```

This should reinitialize the audio and perhaps reload drivers.

Comment: it does bring back sound/mic functionality but has left OS UI out of sync with the hardware, the audio controls in Apple menu appear to be greyed out, and volume up/down keys shows disabled sign.

Comment: following seems to get everything back in normal working conditions:
sudo kill `ps -ax | grep 'coreaudiod' | grep 'sbin' |awk '{print $1}'`
src: https://gist.github.com/felipecsl/5177790

Comment: Hint : you should avoid putting your sound at maximum before executing this command. After resetting the sound, I could not lower the volume for some seconds and the sound was very loud.

Comment: Sometime you need to terminate the process using `kill -9` to make it work.

Comment: sudo killall -9 coreaudiod

Comment: amazing, worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 7):

Try quitting CoreAudio from activity monitor, forcing it to relaunch itself.

Comment: That's the kind of thing I was looking for, but didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: This is cool and it worked for me..

Comment: Unfortunately, CoreAudio is such an integral part to pretty much every Cocoa based Mac application so when it starts messing up, many aspects of the OS go haywire until it's s restarted. It also makes isolating the issue is difficult. =/

Comment: Stopping coreaudiod from activity monitor worked for me!

Answer (score 3):

This answer is based on a comment on @morphos' answer.

> Headphones work, but it doesn't work when I take them out. The
>   prefpane changes to "Digital Out" of type "Optical digital out port"
>   and doesn't let me even change the volume. (the volume controls faded
>   and hitting volume keys shows a crossed out sign)

That means that it thinks you have an optical toslink cable connected. Hold down <kbd>option</kbd> and click the volume button in the menu. Now select "Internal Speakers"

Alternatively, you could go to `System Preferences > Sound > Output` and select `Internal Speakers`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using headphones with your MBP? This thing happens when you take the phones out? Just plug them back make the sound go up and down gently pressing  F11 or F12 (a few keystrokes). Unplug it and keep pressing the F11 or F12 keys until you hear it...

Comment: Headphones work, but it doesn't work when I take them out.  The prefpane changes to "Digital Out" of type "Optical digital out port" and doesn't let me even change the volume. (the volume controls faded and hitting volume keys shows a crossed out sign)

Answer (score 1):

I clicked on System Preferences then chose Sound, clicked on the Sound Effects Tab and then double clicked any sound effect and the sound returned.

Answer (score 0):

You want this:

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
```

Checked and works on High Sierra. Taken from [here](https://superuser.com/questions/647396/reload-mac-audio-drivers-without-rebooting).

Comment: This gives an error message every time I try it. `(kernel) Can't unload kext com.apple.driver.AppleHDA; classes have instances:` (some classes and instance counts) `Failed to unload com.apple.driver.AppleHDA - (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload).` Then the sound becomes completely unresponsive, icon grayed out, function keys not working etc.

Answer (score 0):

The command `sudo killall coreaudiod` worked for my MacBook Air when the speaker volume went low after disconnecting the AirPods.

Answer (score 0):

The following is a standard pattern I used to kill a process *coreaudiod*

```
sudo kill -9 $(ps -ef | grep coreaudiod | grep -v grep |awk '{print $2}')
```

This worked whereas the several others I tried from above or in comments did not.